# How to retrieve DropDown value when it is posted?

Tags: php

When the Form is submitted, I can retrieve the DropDown text using $_POST['....']. But I want to get the DropDown value not the display member. How to get it using POST?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify the difference between "DropDown value" and "display member".  An example might be good.

Comment: <option value="1">First</option>. Here value = 1 and display member = First

Comment: Can you post some example code of the generated HTML? It looks like you're doing it the right way, probably just a typo or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set a `value` attribute to your options, with HTML like this:

```
<select name="foo">
  <option value="bar">Some text</option>
</select>
```

your `$_POST` array will contain `'foo' => 'bar'`.

Comment: When the DropDown is filled dynamically, how I will come to know which option was selected. In that case, how to use $_POST['  ' => ];

Comment: Same deal, just make sure that, when filling the dropdown, you also automatically fill in the `value` attributes !

Comment: They are filling, but I want to know how to call them when using $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify it in the `value` attribute of the `<option>` element. E.g.

```
<select name="dropdownname">
    <option value="valueYouWant1">Label which is displayed 1</option>
    <option value="valueYouWant2">Label which is displayed 2</option>
    <option value="valueYouWant3">Label which is displayed 3</option>
</select>
```

This way the selected value (one of the `valueYouWant*` values) is available by `$_POST['dropdownname']`.

Comment: I guess it is the Text not the Value.

Comment: I guess you have to be more clear in your question and understand the technical meanings. You think X while it is **actually** Y.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re talking about the [`SELECT` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-SELECT), the value of an option is the value of the `value` attribute or the content of that `OPTION` element itself if `value` is missing:

```
<option value="foo">bar</option> <!-- value is "foo" -->
<option>baz</option>             <!-- value is "baz" -->
```

So declare a `value` attribute for your options if you don’t want to contents to be the values of your options.

Comment: It is there, but how to get it in $_POST?

Comment: @RPK: In my example the values would be available with the name of the `SELECT` element: `<select name="name-of-select-element"> … </select>` → `$_POST['name-of-select-element']`. So if the first option is selected, `$_POST['name-of-select-element']` is `"foo"` and `"baz"` when the second one is selected.

Comment: I guess you are wrong. The first line in your post is correct, but the second one is wrong.